# How to get the maximum 2D Tensor from a 3D tensor using TensorFlow 1.14?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I am looking for the best and optimized way (without loops) to get a 2D max Tensor from a 3D Tensor based on the maximum one value using TensorFlow 1.14. let's say we have this Tensor and this function(for understanding-it's not working-):

```
def get_Max(inputs):
    max_indices = [0,0,0]
    for i in range(16):
        for j in range(2048):
            for k in range(10):
                if(inputs[max_indices[0],max_indices[1],max_indices[2]]<inputs[i,j,k]):
                   max_indices = [i,j,k]
    return inputs[:][j]
inputs = tf.random.uniform(shape=[16,2048,10],dtype=tf.dtypes.float32)
output = get_Max(inputs)
```

So, output tensor must have a shape of [16,10], which are the 16 maximums from 2048.
So, How can implement a function that can do this without loops ?

I used `tf.math.reduce_max` but it's not what i am looking for as it's clear in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe `tf.math.reduce_max(inputs)`? or `argmax` if you need the indices as well?

Comment: but how to return a [16,10] Tensor ?

Comment: You can specify an axis too loop over, so instead of finding the maximum across all dimensions, it'll loop over that dimension and then drops it.

Comment: I mean, `tf.math.reduce_max(inputs, axis=1)`

Comment: I know to pass these indices to the inputs and get inputs with shape [16,10]

Comment: As far as I understand your question and the example, using `axis=1` will do what you want. Did I understand it incorrectly?

Comment: No, it's not, look what i am looking for in this [image](https://ibb.co/2NGZRrD)

Answer (score 1):

```
inp = tf.random.uniform(shape=[4, 6, 2], maxval=20, dtype=tf.int32)
print(inp)

array([[[14,  8],
    [18, 10],
    [ 6, 14],
    [ 8,  9],
    [11, 11],
    [14, 13]],

   [[ 7, 18],
    [ 4, 10],
    [15,  6],
    [ 6,  2],
    [19, 11],
    [10,  4]],

   [[ 8,  1],
    [ 1,  3],
    [ 4, 17],
    [15,  7],
    [ 0,  0],
    [ 1,  4]],

   [[ 5,  0],
    [15, 12],
    [ 1, 16],
    [ 3, 17],
    [14, 17],
    [ 2, 18]]], dtype=int32)>
```

So if I understood correctly, for each `inp[i, :, :]` like:

```
    [[14,  8],
    [18, 10],
    [ 6, 14],
    [ 8,  9],
    [11, 11],
    [14, 13]]
```

you want to keep the item that contains the max number, in this case the second row: `[18, 10]`. What I'd do is to first find the max number along the last axis:

```
am = tf.math.reduce_max(inp, axis=2)
am[0, :, :]
[14,
 18,
 14,
 9,
 11,
 14]
```

and then find the index of the row that contains the max number:

```
am = tf.math.argmax(am, axis=1)
```

These will be the `j`s you want, then you can use `tf.gather_nd` and enumerate to get those values:

```
# [*enumerate(am)] = [(0, am[0]), (1, am[1]), ...]
tf.gather_nd(inp, [*enumerate(am)])

<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[18, 10],
       [19, 11],
       [ 4, 17],
       [ 2, 18]], dtype=int32)>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: PS. i got a SyntaxError: invalid syntax in Python2.7, in line tf.gather_nd(inp, [*enumerate(am)]) it points to the *

Comment: @RaniaRano In Python2 you can change `[*enumerate(blah)]` to just `enumerate(blah)`

Comment: @mohammed Jafar it doesn't work because we can't iterate over a tensor in TensorFlow 1.14

Comment: @RaniaRano Can you do `am.numpy()` in 1.14? If not, maybe you could use something along the lines of `tf.stack(tf.range(tf.shape(am)[0]), am)` to do what `enumerate` does?

Comment: numpy() function doesn't work in 1.14.
Don't worry i found the solution, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63537430/the-asterisk-in-tf-gather-nd-in-python2-7-rise-syntax-error/63559483#63559483)