# the asterisk in tf.gather_nd in python2.7 rise syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am using Python2.7, and I can't update it, and I have this line of code, which raise an error at the asterisk, and I don't know why? And how to fix!

```
inp = tf.random.uniform(shape=[4, 6, 2], maxval=20, dtype=tf.int32)

out = tf.math.reduce_max(inp, axis=2)
am = tf.math.argmax(out, axis=1)
o = tf.gather_nd(inp, [*enumerate(am)])
```

This code is about getting a 2D max Tensor from a 3D Tensor based on the maximum one value using TensorFlow 1.14. Like the image below illustrate:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand how you want to pick the values from `inp`. In the first 6x2 submatrix, you highlight in green the first row, which is the row containing the greatest value in the submatrix (0.824). But, in the second submatrix, you highlight the fourth row, which does not contain the greatest value in the submatrix, nor even the greatest value from either column. What exactly is it that you need? The rows with the greatest value, the rows with the greatest value in the first column, something else?

Comment: sorry,I did a mistake in highlighting, i didn't noticed. i want the rows with the greatest value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error in your question has been [explained by BoarGules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63537613/1782792). With respect to the problem that you are trying to solve, you can get the result you want with something like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    # In TF 2.x: tf.random.set_seed
    tf.random.set_random_seed(0)
    # Input data
    inp = tf.random.uniform(shape=[4, 6, 2], maxval=100, dtype=tf.int32)

    # Find index of greatest value in last two dimensions
    s = tf.shape(inp)
    inp_res = tf.reshape(inp, [s[0], -1])
    max_idx = tf.math.argmax(inp_res, axis=1, output_type=s.dtype)
    # Get row index dividing by number of columns
    max_row_idx = max_idx // s[2]
    # Get rows with max values
    res = tf.gather_nd(inp, tf.expand_dims(max_row_idx, axis=1), batch_dims=1)
    # Print input and result
    print(*sess.run((inp, res)), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[[[22 78]
  [75 70]
  [31 10]
  [67  9]
  [70 45]
  [ 5 33]]

 [[82 83]
  [82 81]
  [73 58]
  [18 18]
  [57 11]
  [50 71]]

 [[84 55]
  [80 72]
  [93  1]
  [98 27]
  [36  6]
  [10 95]]

 [[83 24]
  [19  9]
  [46 48]
  [90 87]
  [50 26]
  [55 62]]]
[[22 78]
 [82 83]
 [98 27]
 [90 87]]
```

Answer (score 2):

That asterisk syntax is not available in Python 2. It was added in Python 3.5 (PEP 448) which was 7 years ago.

The Python 2 equivalent was

```
o = tf.gather_nd(inp, [(i,j) for (i,j) in enumerate(am)])
```

But you *really should not* be using Python 2 or investing time in learning it. You don't have to "update" your existing Python 2 installation, if you need it to run legacy code. You can have Python 3.8 running side-by-side with Python 2 if you want. For work reasons I have 3.8, 3.7, 3.6 and 2.7 side-by-side on my machine without problems.

Comment: I got this error, TypeError: Tensor objects are only iterable when eager execution is enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
You didn't noticed that i am working on TensorFlow 1.14

Comment: In that case you have 2 alternatives. Use Python 3.5 or later, or follow the advice in the error message. You did ask about the syntax error.